Superclass Function
How does the flow of inheritance work?
class A:
    def method1(self):
        print("one")

class B(A):
    def method1(self):
        print("two")
        super().method1()

class C(A):
    def method1(self):
        print("three")
        super().method1()

class D(B, C):
    def method1(self):
        print("four")
        super().method1()

d = D()
d.method1()

Why is the output not:
four
two
one
three
one

But it is:
four
two
three
one

Why is the super function in class B overlooked, leading to only one of the 'one's being printed?

Specifically refer to this answer, in short, the MRO (method resolution order) for the instantiated class is referenced, duplicates are removed, before the relevant methods are called.
